# Erro server timezone is unrecognized wildfly 14 Connector/J 8.0.13

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, wildfly

Estou configurando meu ambiente utilizando o wildfly 14.0.1.Final e o connector mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.

Estou com o seguinte erro quando configuro o connection profile e faço um teste de conexão:

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Horário brasileiro de verão' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Meu datasource no arquivo standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySQL-DS" pool-name="MySQL" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pegasus?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=Brazil/East</connection-url>
  <driver>mysql</driver>
  <security>
    <user-name>pegasus_admin</user-name>
      <password>pegasus_admin</password>
  </security>
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MySQL, quando não tem um timezone default, tenta pegar o timezone do Windows, mas esse timezone está num formato que ele não reconhece.

Correção para o problema, setar a variável global time_zone do servidor.

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+3:00';
```

Answer (score -1):

Dependendo da versão do seu Mysql, tente usar assim:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pegasus?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>
```

Ou assim

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pegasus?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>
```